# Keeping the same order in arrays - Brain Teaser?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

*** I need the output to be a matrix because a much larger part of the code needs the output of this code to be a matrix for it's input***

Hello. I have a question related to matrix manipulation.

I need to keep the order the same in the matrix. Please see below for what I am trying to do.

lets say I start out with 3 fruits:

```
fruits = {'apple','orange','berry'};
```

and the amounts of each fruit:

```
amount = [3,5,2]
```

then the next day the amount changes:

```
amount = [2,4,3]
```

so now, my matrix will be:

```
3  5  2
2  4  3
```

but what if the next day I needed to add another fruit:

```
fruits = {'apple','orange','berry','banana'};
```

and the amounts are:

```
amount = [3,4,2,1]
```

how do I make my new matrix like this:

```
3  5  2  NaN
2  4  3  NaN
3  4  2  1
```

then on the next day, I was not given 1 of the original fruits:

```
fruits = {'apple','berry','banana'};
```

and the amount would be:

```
amount = [5,1,4]
```

then I need the matrix to be like the following:

```
3  5  2  NaN
2  4  3  NaN
3  4  2  1
5  NaN  1  4
```

How would I write the code for it to be able to handle all of these situations?

Comment: Seems like you know what your problem is. What have you tried so far? This is extremely basic Matlab –something you'd learn your first day [doing](http://mathworks.com/videos/working-with-arrays-in-matlab-69022.html) [tutorials](http://matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab) or by looking at the [excellent](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html). StackOverflow is not a substitute for spending the time to learn this yourself.

Comment: @horchler Yes. thank you. I figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

use structures then convert struct2cell and convert empties to NaNs